# When can a guild be cloned based on Olympia's B stage 3?

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-leaders

I think I know the answer here, but I just need confirmation.
**Main question**
Olympia B third wonder stage allows you to clone a guild from a neighbor. Does this happen before or after the military conflict of age 3?

I assume "after the military conflict", but....

**What spawned this question**
Scenario:
Player 1 plays with Olympia B and build all 3 stages. He has 3 military shields after the last turn in age 3.
Player 2 (neighbor of Player 1) has build Courtesan's guild (that allows you to clone a leader from a neighbor) and has 4 military shields after the last turn in age 3. 2 of these shields come from a leader (not the cloned one though).

Dilemma:
If player 1 clones the the Courtesan's guild and then clones the leader that gives him 2 military shields (making him have 5 shields in total), does he win the military conflict of age 3 or he clones it for nothing because the cloning takes place after the military conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules (page 9) say:

> for the third stage, the choice of the Guild is made at the end of the game, when counting points. The player totals the victory points as they had built that Guild.

Since Courtesan's guild gives no victory points, selecting it will be no use for the player. Note that, Olympia B was designed at a time when all guilds were effective only during scoring.

See [here](https://rpggeek.com/thread/651410/olympia-b-stage-3-copying-courtesans-guild) for more discussion.

Comment: "Since Courtesan's guild gives no victory points, selecting it will be no use for the player"...I don't know about this. Doesn't this let you clone a leader that could give your points? Anyway...that's not relevant for my question. The main question was, is the guild cloned before or after the military conflict of the third age. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Marius I think you are right. I could have used better wording.